# Creating a pool of tasks/jobs with a limited amount of workers (ThreadPool) by using parallel toolbox

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I would like to use the parallel computing toolbox to speed up a set of function calls that do not depend on each other. To make this more efficient I would like to use timer functions/callback functions to continually execute more of the functions after one of my function finishes executing. I don't know ahead of time which ones will be faster, so I can't just divide my set of functions into a few pools and set them up going in parallel.

In other words, I would like a few parallel executions to keep pulling from a pool of functions.

The only way I have this set up now I have a cell array of strings that I use `str2fun` on, is there a better way to do this?

Questions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to write such code by yourself. The Matlab parallel toolbox has the ability to create a [scheduler with multiple jobs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brkl0o6.html#f5-18839). 
You can call `createJob` multiple times, and the scheduler will do the pulling.

```
 foos = [@foo1,@foo2,@foo3,@foo4]
 for i=1:numel(foos)
     obj = createJob();
     createTask(obj, foos(i), 1, {'your input'});
     submit(obj);
 end
```

[image]

Comment: Cell arrays of function handles work better than ordinary arrays - to avoid confusion between indexing into the array, and evaluating the function handle. In fact, in R2011b, you cannot concatenate function handles.

Comment: Thanks, @Edric. Isn't there an overhead to calling `eval` instead of applying the function handle?

Comment: You don't need to call `eval` - but you might need `feval` (perhaps that's what you meant). I don't know for sure, but I doubt there's much difference (if any) between evaluating a function handle directly and calling `feval`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something simpler like:

```
matlabpool 3

parfor t=1:3
  if t==1
    a1=f1();
  end
  if t==2
    a2=f2();
  end
  if t==3
    a3=f3();
  end
end
```