# Job dispatching rules

Tags: matlab, dispatch, job-scheduling

Is there any Matlab orientated code of commonly used job dispatch rules, such as EDD, SPT or FIFO?
I found only [TORSCHE toolbox](http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox/), but its pretty hard to understand it as a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: What about parallel processing toolbox?

Comment: @Andrey Well, i have not tried it. But on first look at Matlab docs, I think it won't help. Basically, I want a several functions that implements the aforementioned rules, so I can build my on algorithms further. I have several ideas regarding NN or GA, but I can't start without these basic elements since I'm not a scheduling expert. But thanks for replying.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042335/creating-a-pool-of-tasks-jobs-with-a-limited-amount-of-workers-threadpool-by-u/9045682#9045682 Does this help you?

Comment: Also checkout http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/createtask.html

Comment: @Andrey I think not. As I understood it, this scheduler just postpones some jobs (or functions) until the previous one is finished. But how can I use NN to approximate some job or how can I set up uniform distribution for some specific job time. I think the answer is far more simpler, and it can be done without using build-in toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB supports some third-party schedulers.  The following page lists them, as well as gives some minimal insight on the native MATLAB job manager.  According to this documentation, "For advanced resource and security management features, you must use a third-party scheduler."

http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/supported/sched/level_of_support.html#directly

Answer (score 0):

Some people have directed you towards how to dispatch CPU jobs.
However as I read it, my guess would be that you are talking about jobs in Operations Research.

In that case the solution i would recommend would be:
Simply program a small function for each rule that you want to use, and matching the input that you have. Then it is easy to re-use this function in each bit of code that you have.

The reason why this may not be standard functionality is due to the variety of input formats and ease of programming it yourself.

A tip on how to do this for e.g. EDD and SPT: Just sort them according to the respective property and then take the first available one each time.